# Interview question interface implementation

Tags: c++, interface

Could your please help me with following interview question.

Given function ‪`Sleep(int seconds)` implement following interface so timers could be used:

- function ‪`void CreateTimer(void (*func)(), int seconds)` that her purpose is to create timer
- function ‫‪`void StartTimers()` that her purpose to start all the timers

Every timer that started should delay for several seconds and then use a callback to call a function.
Example:

```
CreateTimer(func1,3);
CreateTimer(func2,7);
CreateTimer(func3,10);
StartTimers()
```

The folowing should be happening:

Delay for 3 seconds and then call for function 1.
Delay for 4 seconds and then call for function 2.
Delay for 3 seconds and then call for function 3.

The question is how implement such interface?

Comment: If this is a interview question in your interview, shouldn't you be answering it yourself?

Comment: It wasn't in my interview .There are many interview questions in this site that people ask here so I don't see any special problem

Comment: Do timers all start at the same time, or run one after another? If the former, then it can only work if the callbacks take negligible time to execute. Otherwise the delays will be off.

Comment: all the timers is start at the same time and yes the callbacks time are negligble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT 1: Use the questions API.

EDIT 2: Oops, didn't call q.pop();

This sounds like a job for [`std::priority_queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/), ordered by deadline.

```
//pseudo-code
class Job;
std::priority_queue<Job, std::vector<Job>, CompareLessByDeadline> q;

CreateTimer(func, deadline) {
   q.push(Job(func, deadline));
}
StartTimers() {
  now = 0;
  while(!q.empty()) {
    Job& j = q.top();
    Sleep(j.deadline-now);
    now = j.deadline;
    j.function();
    q.pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The psuedo code could be something like >

1. Create a global dictionary of type
2. In create timer function, keep adding the two parameters in the dictionary
3. In start timer function, call each of the funcs after a Sleep of their respective value in the dictionary

Comment: You don't really need a dictionary here. Any ordered list/array/vector will do.

Comment: you'll require to keep track of the time against each function. so a single dimension array/list won't work. You need two dimensions.

Comment: I meant a list of functions paired with delays, of course. I'm just saying that since you want them back out in the same order you put them in, there is no need for a dictionary.

Comment: @hammar: yea, it was just a psuedo code. I don't think C++ have an inherent dictionary type. but point taken regarding the order. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
//globals vector v1; vector v2;

CreateTimer(func, delay) {  
v1.push_back(func);  
v2.push_back(delay); }


StartTimers() {   startDelay=0;  
for(i=0; i<v2.size; i++)   {
    sleep(v2[i]-startDelay);
    *v1[i]   //call the function
    startDelay=v2[i];   }

}
```